# Form with weighted answers

Tags: javascript, php, forms, weighted

I need help creating a weighted form - which seems to means a lot of things to different people. Essentially, we want to walk a customer through a 20 question - questionnaire. A Question may have 2, 3, 4, or 5 answers in a radial button format, depending on how they answer that question, it would add a value to a category.

For Example:
Q1: Which of the following will be your priority in 2015?
A1: Recruiting  (Adds (#value) to following categories: Product A (1) Product B (2) Product C (0) )
A2: Training new reruits  (Adds Product A (2) Product B (0) Product C (0) )
A3: Increasing performance of lower performers ( Adds Product A (0) Product B (2) Product C (1) )
A4: Opening new branches (Adds Product A (0) Product B (0) Product C (2) )

At the end of the quiz, a suggestion would be made of a certain product based on the totals for each category.

I do not have much knowledge of javascript, but am learning PHP. I am much better at reading and editing various languages than I am writing my own, so any suggestions on how to carry this task out would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No JavaScript needed.

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php">
  ...
  Question 1:
  <input type="radio" name="answer[0]" value="1,2,0">
  <input type="radio" name="answer[0]" value="2,0,0">
  ...
</form>
```

and then in PHP, you can collect

```
$answers = $_POST["answer"];
$results = [0, 0, 0];
foreach ($answers as $answer) {
  $values = explode(",", $answer);
  for ($p = 0; $p < 3; $p++) {
    $results[$p] += $values[$p];
  }
}
```